# Comparing value in same column and directing output to new column

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, awk, columns

I have my input file as

```
DPortal=ECCN RemoteFile=4004_130122 0256 A02 141111 0940 29343414 11  110005
DPortal=ECCN RemoteFile=4004_130122 0256 A02 141111 2336 29843714 11  110006
DPortal=ECCN RemoteFile=4004_130122 0256 A02 141111 0940 29343214 11  110007
DPortal=ECCN RemoteFile=4004_130122 0256 A02 141111 2336 29843914 11  110009
DPortal=ECCN RemoteFile=4004_120306 1232 A03 141111 2336 7945414  11  110010
DPortal=ECCN RemoteFile=4004_130122 0256 A02 141111 0940 29343314 11  110013
DPortal=ECCN RemoteFile=4004_120306 1232 A03 141111 2336 7945614  11  110015
DPortal=ECCN RemoteFile=4004_130122 0256 A02 141111 0941 29343514 11  110019
DPortal=ECCN RemoteFile=4004_120306 1232 A03 141111 0941 7446214  11  110021
DPortal=ECCN RemoteFile=4004_120306 1232 A03 141111 2336 7945814  11  110022
DPortal=ECCN RemoteFile=4004_120306 1232 A03 141111 0941 7446414  11  110024
```

and my requirement is to have output as follows

```
DPortal=ECCN RemoteFile=4004_130122 0256 A02 141111 0940 29343414 11 110005  0
DPortal=ECCN RemoteFile=4004_130122 0256 A02 141111 2336 29843714 11 110006  0
DPortal=ECCN RemoteFile=4004_130122 0256 A02 141111 0940 29343214 11 110007  0
DPortal=ECCN RemoteFile=4004_130122 0256 A02 141111 2336 29843914 11 110009  1
DPortal=ECCN RemoteFile=4004_120306 1232 A03 141111 2336 7945414  11 110010  0
DPortal=ECCN RemoteFile=4004_130122 0256 A02 141111 0940 29343314 11 110013  2
DPortal=ECCN RemoteFile=4004_120306 1232 A03 141111 2336 7945614  11 110015  1
DPortal=ECCN RemoteFile=4004_130122 0256 A02 141111 0941 29343514 11 110019  3
DPortal=ECCN RemoteFile=4004_120306 1232 A03 141111 0941 7446214  11 110021  1
DPortal=ECCN RemoteFile=4004_120306 1232 A03 141111 2336 7945814  11 110022  0 
DPortal=ECCN RemoteFile=4004_120306 1232 A03 141111 0941 7446414  11 110024  1
```

i.e the last column should print the value of last column's next row -1
i.e (n+1) -n -1 =next column.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
awk 'NR==1{last=$NF-1}{print $0,$NF-last-1; last=$NF}' file
```

At first row we set variable `last` to a value of last field minus 1 (`$NF-1`), just for start. Later on `last` takes just value of `$NF` from previous row.

Comment: Thanks it helped but how can i redirect this output to last column of my file

Comment: What do you mean by "redirect to last column"? The output is as in your question - all previous columns + additional one. If you want to redirect the whole output to some file just add `> outputfile` at the end of the command line.